# ADBannerView touch disabled

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, iad, adbannerview

It's 3 days I'm trying to resolve a problem in my app.

I have an ADBannerView (added programmatically) that correctly displays ad, but when I click it, nothing happens (it seem like disabled).

Here's the result of

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
NSLog(@"%@",banner);
}



<ADBannerView: 0x1f060d00; frame = (0 454; 320 50); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1f0745f0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1f0613b0>>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: 454 seems off screen to me. Maybe change the frame so that it is at (0, 430 (or 410 if you have a status bar), 320, 50).

Comment: Do you have the delegate of AdBannerView in your .h?